# Why this command does not work from cron.daily file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a file in cron.daily:

```
root@nagios.example.com:/# cat /etc/cron.daily/nagios-logs
/usr/bin/nice -n 19 /bin/gzip --fast /var/log/nagios3/archives/*
root@nagios.example.com:/# ls -l /etc/cron.daily/nagios-logs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 65 Apr 15 17:51 /etc/cron.daily/nagios-logs
root@nagios.example.com:/#
```

but it's not doing anything. Any ideas why?

Comment: How did you know it is not executing? Did you try it manually?

Comment: @Khaled It does not compress uncompressed files in `/var/log/nagios3/archives/`. When I execute it manually it works.

Comment: Why not have it in a script? That way you define the shell..

Comment: Did you try appending `>> /tmp/file.log 2>&1` to see if there is any debug/error?

Comment: @NickW the output of `cat` command is full and not edited

Comment: @Khaled good advice. I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file **/etc/cron.daily/nagios-logs** is neither a program nor an executable script. You can make it a shell script by adding **#!/bin/sh** to the beginning of the file

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/nice -n 19 /bin/gzip --fast /var/log/nagios3/archives/*
```

The shell script also needs to be executable

```
root@nagios.example.com:/# chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/nagios-logs
```

but I see from the output of your `ls -l` command that your file already has the correct file permissions